# Why does Debian require a restart for login to self hosted Docker Repo after new SSL and Ubuntu does NOT x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: debian, ubuntu, docker, ssl

I have two servers, one Debian Buster (Debian 4.19.208-1) and the other is Ubuntu 18 (Ubuntu 18.04.6).

I recently updated the SSL on a self hosted Docker Image Repo and noticed that on the Ubuntu system, I was able to login/pull etc. without doing anything, but on the Debian instance, I got `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

Threads online mention doing a `docker restart` but at that point, I might as well restart the entire server. This is not ideal as it means taking down each service. I just tested and it did work. I have another Debian server that is in production that I'd like to fix without rebooting.

Any ideas why this behavior is happening and a way I can avoid having to reboot server on Debian?

Comment: Just restart the service, don't reboot the whole docker.

Comment: @IporSircer I'm not sure what you mean, doesn't `docker restart` restart every container?

Comment: related (or so I think): https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/

Comment: @A.B that may very well do the trick! I have to find a time to test when its OK if PROD does go down, then I could report back. You could write up an answer if you prefer and I can accept once it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's documentation [Keep containers alive during daemon downtime](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/) explains that by using

> ```yaml
> {
>   "live-restore": true
> }
> ```

(or anyway appending at the top level of the existing configuration `"live-restore": true`) in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` one can restart Docker without Docker stopping its containers during this operation.

So the way to do this for the first time is to:

- add the configuration
- *reload* Docker so it uses this newer option
- *restart* Docker which now will not stop its containers and recover their state information

Caveat: there are limitations:

- Docker network's settings should not change for involved containers
- if about an upgrade, only patch release upgrades (`YY.MM.x` where only `x` changes) will respect the feature.
- not valid for Docker Swarm
- If Docker is stopped for too long, logs fom containers might make their FIFO buffer full

and any other restriction in the linked documentation.

Comment: I've decided to accept, but this didn't work on Debian 9. Truth is that OS is too dated for me to complain anyway.